# How to make Struts and Prototype work better together?

Tags: prototypejs, struts

Prototype library uses `$('element-id')` or `$F('element-id')` to get the element or value of a form element. This is very convenient to code in javascript. But in Struts, I find there is no way to define an id attribute for a form element.

Although i can use

```
<html:xhtml/>
```

to define a form tag with id attribute as follows:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>

<html:xhtml/> 

<html:form action="/Welcome">
...
<html:text property="username" size="16" maxlength="18"/>
...
</html:form>
```

The above rendered html is like this:

```
<form id="TestForm" method="post" action="/myapp/Welcome.do">
...
<input type="text" name="username" size="16" maxlength="18"/>
...
</form>
```

But what i need is to let struts render the

```
<html:text>
```

tag like this:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="16" maxlength="18"/>
```

So is it possible in Struts to realize that? Or if not, how can i make it better to code in Prototype lib for Struts application?

I am using Struts 1.3.8; Prototype 1.5.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *styleId* attribute on most Struts widgets to set the HTML element id:

```
<html:text styleId="myId" .../>
```

renders as

```
<input type="text" id="myId" .../>
```